AWS Systems manager concurrency limit
I have a limited access to an AWS account on which I am trying to trigger some SSM Commands. I am basically triggering them using lambda from step functions as part of some workflows. I have recently implemented a change and as part of it, I will have to run SSM commands in parallel. During testing, I came to know that some other workflow SSM commands are timing out because of lambda 15 minutes limitation as they seem to be waiting in Queue for my workflow SSM commands to complete. I don't have Service Quotas permission and CLI also gave me permission denied error for Quota listing. I tried to search for SSM config file in etc/amazon/ssm/ path but I could only find the amazon-ssm-agent.json.template file but no main file to check the actual concurrency limit. I tried to see the number of parallel commands running in SSM console and could see some 18 in progress commands at once, so the quota is definitely not the default 5.
Is there any other way I could find the Quota before reaching out to client admin team?
